# How would I query for a relationship between these two nodes?

Tags: neo4j

If I have a graph that looks like so for nodes (p) and (e):

```
(p:Person)-[r:WorksFor]->(e:Employer)
```

And I have the following data:

```
(Person {name: Andrew})-[r:WorksFor]->(Employer {name: Google})
(Person {name: James})-[r:WorksFor]->(Employer {name: Google})
(Person {name: James})-[r:WorksFor]->(Employer {name: Apple})
(Person {name: Evan})-[r:WorksFor]->(Employer {name: Apple})
```

How can I query between (Person {name: Evan}) through each relationship and get to (Person {name: Andrew}) returning each employer and person along the way with an arbitrary number of employers and persons in-between?

Ideally the above would return a chain that looked like:

```
(Andrew)->(Google)->(James)->(Apple)->(Evan)
```

Thank you for your help.

(EDIT) Addendum:

The following seems to work but only if the players are separated by only two degrees, is there a way to make this completely variable length?

```
MATCH 
(p:Person {name: "Andrew"})-->(e:Employer)<--(p3:Person)-->(e2:Employer)<--(p2:Person {name: "Evan"}) 
RETURN *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want [variable-length pattern matching](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/patterns/#cypher-pattern-varlength).

Depending on your graph you can define the relationships to traverse or leave off the type. We can omit the direction to specify that we don't care about the direction of relationships to traverse:

```
MATCH path = (p:Person {name: "Andrew"})-[:WorksFor*]-(p2:Person {name: "Evan"}) 
RETURN path
```

If you want the nodes in the path, you can return `nodes(path)` to get that list.

If you only want the shortest path between these two, you can match to both then match using the shortestPath function:

```
MATCH (p:Person {name: "Andrew"}), (p2:Person {name: "Evan"}) 
MATCH path = shortestPath((p)-[:WorksFor*]-(p2))
RETURN path
```

Comment: Could this easily lead to out of memory issues if the person count is say, 4000 and the employer count is 30 given ~ 40 or so years of data with constant switching?

I guess the question is really: how taxing is this given an extremely dense dataset?

EDIT: I ask as this seems to completely time out my dataset.

Comment: ShortestPath() is probably your best bet in a dense graph. An unbounded variable-length relationship in any moderately connected graph may hang, especially as you're asking for all possible paths, which can blow through the heap easily. If you don't care about all possible paths and only need a single path, then you have more options. If your requirements are different than what you have in the question above, you may want to consider asking as a separate question.